# How to calculate the expected value in the following box?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose there is a box containing tickets $1,2,2,3$, and we take $2$ draws from the box in order. let's call the first number drawn $X$, and the second number draw $Y$. Then we call the number $Z=X\times Y$ and $U=Z^2$.

If it is **with** replacement, what are the possible values and the expected value of U?

In my opinion, if it is **with** replacement, the possible values for $Z$ would be $1,2,3,4,6,9$ (from$1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,9$). Thus $U$ would contain $1,4,9,16,36,81$ (from$1,4,4,4,4,9,9,16,16,16,16,36,36,36,36,81$). The expected value for $U$ would be $\frac{1+4\times 4+9\times 2+16\times 4+36\times 4+81}{16}=20.25$.

But I am not sure if I did it correctly. Could someone clarify?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is okay.  Just to double check:

If it is *with replacement*, the variables are independent, and thus $\mathsf E(U)=\mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(Y^2)$

Now $\mathsf E(X^2) =\frac{1^2+2\cdot 2^2+3^2}{4} = \frac{18}4$

Thus $\mathsf E(U)=\frac{324}{16}$, confirming your answer.

---

PS: without replacement:

> $$\mathsf E(U) =\frac{324-(1^4+2\cdot 2^4+3^4)}{12} = \frac{210}{12} = 17.5.$$